# FreeBSD 9.2 networking issues on latest VMWare ESXi, any workarounds?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, freebsd

We just updated our VMWare servers over the weekend and have noted that all of our FreeBSD 9.2 guests are having networking issues.  Specifically, ipv4 no longer functions (they can't even see equipment on the same subnet).  IPv6 does still function though.  We've had similar problems in the past and flipping the VMWare interface to another VLAN, then back has fixed it before, but not this time.  We've also had interface names change during VMWare upgrades, but that's not the problem this time either.  Google came up empty.  Thinking this may be a brand new issue with the combination of that VMWare version and FreeBSD 9.2 (our FreeBSD 10.0 VMs are working fine).  Anyone find a workaround yet that we could use to get these VMs IPv4 connectivity again?

Comment: It is a supported combination, did you update the vmtools inside your VMs? this may work but could reenumerate your ports.

Comment: I did do the VMWare Tools update, that also did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things randomly, I finally found a way to make them work again.  Shutdown the guest.  Do a disconnect of the VM NIC from the web management tool.  Save that.  Go back in and reconnect the NIC.  Save that.  Start the VM again.

So, similar to the usual "flip the VLAN" trick, but just enough different that we didn't hit on it right away.